# Why are the packets of safale US05 different from the recipes?

Tags: yeast

All the recipes that I've seen ( mainly on Beersmith ) which use Safale US05 quote the size as being 50.28ml but anywhere I see it for sale it's a dry yeast that comes in an 11.5gram sachet. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Not sure. At first I thought maybe it was referring to a liquid substitute, but that would be closer to 125ml. Then I thought maybe 11.5g of dry yeast converted to ml, but the conversion rate (for dry yeast) is 1g=1.75ml, so that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well gram and ml are different types of measurement. Gram is mass, ml is volume.

In this case it's referring to a hydrated yeast slurry volume of about two 11.5g packs of dry yeast or from a starter.

The slurry is the yeast that settles after hydration, so the remaining water is decanted.

This particular yeast is based on a wort of 1.040-1.050 OG. So a recipe calling for 50ml would be for a wort thats about 1.080 OG needing two packs of yeast.